# iOS app begin run on 4" screen like on 3.5"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I don't know, why it happened, but my app begin run on 4" screen like on 3.5"
I can try now only on simulator. I cann't attach image, because I have little reputation

I try delete all in AppDelegate, and in storyboard I create empty ViewController and specify it like first VC for load. Then I reset content and settings in SImulator, but problem still with me o_O

All another app run great on 4" simulator.

Why this problem appeared?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether an app utilized iPhone 5's screen depends of the presence of Default-568h@2x.png file in your app bundle. Have you deleted your launch images?

Comment: Thanks, it help me, maybe I occasionally delete it
I will sign like decision through 10 minutes, I still cann't